# How to remove video placeholder?

Tags: html

I have a video on my website that i have removed controls so it looks like the screen of a cellphone and it auto plays. The problem is that the black video holder appears for a second before the video starts and i want to remove that or hide it.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add poster="placeholder.png" to the video tag.

make the placeholder.png your first frame of your video